# How to update user attributes?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to write a script that updates every user's `msIIS-FTPRoot` attribute where the user's description = ‘FTPuser’.

```
import-module activedirectory
$users = Get-ADUser -SearchBase "dc=NAME,dc=com" -Filter {Description -eq "FTPUser"}
Set-ADUser $users -Replace @{msIIS-FTPRoot='NewTEXT'}
```

I get the following error:

```
Missing '=' operator after key in hash literal.
At line:1 char:60
+ Set-ADUser $users -Replace @{msIIS-FTPRoot='\\SOMETEXT\' <<<< }
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEqualsInHashLiteral
```

Comment: When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617215.aspx).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I don't see anything about the msIIS-FTPRoot attribute.

Comment: Then you need to carefully re-read the description of the parameters `-Add` and `-Replace`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Sorry it takes so long to respond, first time using PowerShell. Am I on the right track?

import-module activedirectory
$users = Get-ADUser -SearchBase "dc=NAME,dc=com" -Filter {Description -eq "FTPUser"}
-Replace @{msIIS-FTPRoot='OldTEXT','NewTEXT'}

Comment: That exact exception is because you need to include quotes around `msIIS-FTPRoot`.  For example `@{"msIIS-FTPRoot"="Foo"}`

Answer (score 1):

Set-ADUser $users -Replace @{'msIIS-FTPRoot'='NewTEXT'}

Answer (score 0):

Using quotation marks on the attribute name solves your problem.